# C# Message Queueing while .wav is playing

Tags: c#, .net, wav

I have a program which plays three .wav files synchronously when a button is clicked. The problem is that even if I disable the button on the first instruction of the click handler, additional mouse click events are queued and then executed when playback completes if the use clicks while sound is playing. How can I avoid this?

Here's my click handler, playSnippet_P1,2,3 play the three audio files in different orders:

```
void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnPlay.Enabled = false;
    this.Refresh();

    //play a snippet for the current passage
    switch (myProgram.condition)
    {
        case 1:
            playSnippet_P1();
            break;
        case 2:
            playSnippet_P2();
            break;
        case 3:
            playSnippet_P3();
            break;
        default:
            if (myProgram.debug)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error(frmPassage): Invalid condition set: " + myProgram.condition);
            }
            break;
    }

    //leave this phase once final passage is finished
    if (snipsPlayed >= (myProgram.snipCount_1 
                        + myProgram.snipCount_2 
                        + myProgram.snipCount_3))
    {
        myProgram.phaseController.runNextPhase();
    }

    //reset the form to show text for next passage
    if (snipsPlayed >= (getSnipCount(1) + getSnipCount(2)))
        currentPassage = 2;
    else if (snipsPlayed >= getSnipCount(1))
        currentPassage = 1;
    else
        currentPassage = 0;

    lblTitle.Text = "Passage " + randPOrder[currentPassage].ToString();

    btnPlay.Enabled = true;
}

private void playSnippet_P1()
    {
        snipsPlayed++;

        int cSnipCount = getCSnipCount();
        int snipNum = (snipsPlayed % cSnipCount);
        int subNum = getSubNum(snipsPlayed);
        if (snipNum == 0)
            snipNum = cSnipCount;

        int rPassage = randPOrder[currentPassage];

        //play "Next question is for..."
        JE_SP.playSound(Application.StartupPath
            + "\\res\\audio\\next\\Next" + subNum.ToString()
            + ".wav", true);

        //play snippet
        JE_SP.playSound(Application.StartupPath
            + "\\res\\audio\\passages\\Snip" + rPassage.ToString()
            + "-" + snipNum.ToString()
            + ".wav", true);

        //play question
        JE_SP.playSound(Application.StartupPath
            + "\\res\\audio\\passages\\Q" + rPassage.ToString()
            + "-" + snipNum.ToString()
            + ".wav", true);

        string[] writeMe = 
            {
                rPassage.ToString(), 
                "\\res\\audio\\passages\\Snip" + rPassage.ToString()
                    + "-" + snipNum.ToString(), 
                "\\res\\audio\\passages\\Q" + rPassage.ToString()
                    + "-" + snipNum.ToString(), 
                subNum.ToString(), 
                myProgram.condition.ToString()
            };

        JE_Log.logData(writeMe, "\t", myProgram.groupFile);
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to run the code that plays the audio on another thread, since the UI is going to be completely unresponsive while in the click handler, queuing up events to be dispatched when control returns to the Winforms main loop.

Comment: can you show the code that plays back a snippet?

Comment: You want to avoid that - but you didn't tell what you want...

Comment: I'm trying to make this a single threaded application and what I want to avoid is queueing messages when sound is playing on that thread. I posted an example of a method that plays the three files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler repro of this behavior:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The problem is that the mouse clicks that are recorded while the UI thread is busy go into the message queue and are stuck there until the event handler completes.  When that happens, the button is already enabled again, allowed the Click event to run again.

Fixing this is fugly and includes paying the price of running the code on a worker thread.  A possible good fix is to purge the message queue and remove all the mouse messages before re-enabling the button but that's not easy in Winforms.  The code is actually there but it is internal.  A really pragmatic fix is one that might get me in trouble but is safe and effective :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (!button1.IsDisposed) button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I think this might be better than what I came up with. Thanks for the suggestion I'll try it out right now. EDIT: I suspect there might be some danger in calling DoEvents() in more sophisticated applications that will result in inconsistent state. But I think it should be OK with my program because of it's simplicity - there are only a few things that can happen during sound playback.

Comment: No, it's completely safe.  Seeing that does require grokking what DoEvents does.  The IsDisposed test is the crucial bit.

Comment: This works and seems more sensible than what I came up with. Thanks for the help. If it's completely safe why would doing this get you in trouble? What did you mean by that?

Comment: For the exact same reason you said "some danger in calling".  DoEvents isn't exactly well understood and got an enormous amount of bad rep back in the VB6 days.  Not unjustified, abuse was rampant.  Many SO visitors instinctively reach for the downvote arrow when they see it being used to solve a problem.  Please close your thread before this happens.  Big check mark next to your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deliberate feature of Windows. It's the same thing that lets you type into a window that's busy - your text appears once the application comes back.

Why not disable the button and play the sounds asynchronously?

Comment: I do disable the button, but I don't want to play the sounds asynchronously because it is important that nothing happens while audio is playing. Do you know of any way to attach data to an event, or tell the message queue to not accept anything from a specific form control?

Comment: You could [attach a message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) and prevent messages arriving at the form. Why don't you want to make the GUI active while the sound plays?

Comment: It is a very simple program (one button), and in this context it would be better to force the user to wait until playback completes. The message filter looks very promising! I'll get back to you in a little bit after I try it out

Comment: Disabling the form should achieve this

Comment: Disabling the form did not work because messages could still be queued and then delivered on return of the click handler (at that point the button is re-enabled). The message filter also did not work... it never seems to call my implementation of PreFilterMessage. I did figure out a solution which involves a timer (see below)

Comment: Disabled forms swallow input messages. You can see this with a modal dialog box: try opening a dialog box then clicking on the application's main window. The clicks on the main window don't get queued.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your description that playsnippet() blocks until the snippet is done playing, so this should be done a separate thread (you can use a BackgroundWorker class). This will avoid your GUI from getting stuck and should also solve the button clicking issue.

When the BackgroundWorker has completed, you can re-enable the button, but make sure to do this on the GUI thread (with Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke)

Good luck.

Comment: The program is single-threaded so nothing blocks. I'm trying not to do any multi-threading if possible. The only issue is the message queuing during audio playback

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is as follows:

In the mouse click handler, disable the button but do no re-enable it when playback completes. Instead start a Forms.Timer with sufficient interval to allow the messages that arrive on the disabled button to be cleared. On the first tick, re-enable the button and stop the timer.

This prevented the additional click events from doing anything because the button would still be disabled. Of course, this solution is very specific to my situation, and I understand usually the solution would be to play audio on a separate thread.

Thanks for all you suggestions!!

EDIT: Hans Passant posted a more sensible solution - see his suggestion on purging the message queue before enabling the control.